# How I show the other field of selected item in document

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a `spinner` which will show the book title. and want to display the price of the selected book. my Firestore database is as follows:

```
 Books (collection)
|
|--- book1 (document)
|    |--- Price : "100"
|    |--- Title : "Book-1"
|
|--- book2
|    |--- Price : "200"
|    |--- Title : "Book-2"
```

When I tried the below codes it displayed the same selected item, Could you please tell me what do I need to add to show the price of the selected book?

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    FirebaseFirestore db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView priceView = findViewById(R.id.price);

        db =  FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        CollectionReference booksRef = db.collection("Books");
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        List<String> booksList = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, booksList);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        booksRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>(){
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        String bt = document.getString("Title");
                        booksList.add(bt);
                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                priceView.setText("Price:  " + adapterView.getItemIdAtPosition(position).);
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
                                          }
        );

    }
```

Comment: `android-studio` tag is used for questions related to the IDE itself. Please use `android` only for app related issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `booksList.add(bt);` just adds book title in adapter view's list so `getItemAtPosition()` will return the book title itself and not the document data. One way would be to store the document data in a separate list as shown below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    FirebaseFirestore db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        TextView priceTextView = findViewById(R.id.price);

        // List to store all document's data
        List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> list = new ArrayList<>();

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new ArrayList<>());
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        CollectionReference colRef = db.collection("books");
        colRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    adapter.add(document.getString("Title"));
                    list.add(document); // <-- add document to list
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        });

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, android.view.View view, int position, long id) {
                // Get book data from the list by position
                QueryDocumentSnapshot book = list.get(position);
                priceTextView.setText(String.valueOf(book.get("Price")));
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Nothing selected");
            }
        });
    }
}
```